# QueryDSL over collections -> any() for a List of Strings

Tags: java, collections, querydsl, jooq

I'm trying to use querydsl over collections.
My list is a `List<String>`.

First question, is it possible to use querydsl over a *primitive* type collection?
Hereafter, how could I build a query like: `give all strings which there aren't in list x`?

I've tried this:

```
String digitalResourceId;
for (String resource : from(digitalResourceId, digitalResourceIds)
                            .where(fua.getResources().any().eq(digitalResourceId))
                            .list(digitalResourceId)){
        System.out.println(resource);
    }
```

However I've compile problem on `any()` method:

```
The method any() is undefined for the type List<String>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<String> x = ...
List<String> output = queryFactory.selectFrom(resource_table.resourceId)
    .where(resource_table.resourceId.notIn(x))
    .fetch();
```